# encodeURIComponent issue in Querystring

Tags: asp.net, query-string, urlencode

I use encodeURIComponent and send it in querystring but when I got it in asp.net page it is change. Here is the Code.

```
var postType = encodeURIComponent($(obj).parents(".post").attr("data-item-type"));
var postId = encodeURIComponent($(obj).parents(".post").attr("data-item"));
window.location.href = "PostDetail.aspx?" + GetGUID() + '&pId=' + postId + '&pType=' + postType;
```

and in asp page

in url it shows the correct "rEpJZ8IDRfIbFpptDl%2B84w%3D%3D&pType=ereq47B7tt0BQMO5nRRbOQ%3D%3D"

but in asp page it is "rEpJZ8IDRfIbFpptDl 84w==" after HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("pId"))

Comment: what is the original value isn't it rEpJZ8IDRfIbFpptDl 84w==?

Answer (score 0):

it is correct.
The other values are in

```
 HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("pType"))
```

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: what is the value before using `encodeURIComponent`